# Wordpress query not filtering by taxonomy when specifying a slug

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called news. Inside that I have two custom taxonomies called press-releases and media-coverage. When I query for multiple posts with this query:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'news_type' => 'press-releases',
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'paged' => $json_api->query->page,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

It only gets news posts categorized as press-releases like I want. But if I specify a slug that exists in media-coverage it returns that post even though I have the press-releases taxonomy specified. Example:

```
$args = array(
            'name' => $slug,
            'post_type' => 'news',
            'news_type' => 'press-releases',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'news',
    'name' => '$slug,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news_type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'press-releases'
        )
    )
);
```